# Segmentation fault (core dump) when extract features in caffe?

Tags: ubuntu, caffe, feature-extraction

When I follow the tutorial about feature extraction using a pre-trained model with caffe, I met some problem.
 As the tutorial says, I have made the temp.txt to generate a list of the files to process. To add expects labels after each filenames I have also made the file_list.txt. Then I used imagenet_mean.binaryproto and imagenet_val.prototxt to define the feature extraction network architecture. After this, I input the command in the terminal like this "./build/tools/extract_features.bin models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel examples/_temp/imagenet_val.prototxt fc7 examples/_temp/features 10 leveldb". 
The expected result is just like the following image shown[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqWT2.png)
While I met the problem just like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vot60.png)
I have found all the necessary files mentioned in the tutorial. I really can not figure out the problem hoping someone will help me. I will be so appreciate! English is not my mother tongue, I hope readers can be more patient.

Comment: Use the python wrapper here http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb

Comment: Sorry , I'm not very clear about what you mean. Until now the python wrapper in my opinion is used to realize the function about filter visualization. I'm going to learn how to use the Python interface for this task. So according to my question , the segmentation fault (core dump), do you have any other suggestions? Thank you so much for your advice!